# Converting the For Next Loop into a For Each Loop

Tags: vb.net

Convert the following For Next Loop into a For Each Loop:

```
Dim TeamString(31) As String

For CounterInteger as Integer = 0 to 31

    MessageBox.Show("Team Name:" & TeamString(CounterInteger))

Next
```

Comment: "Convert the following For Next Loop into a For Each Loop:" : No!

Comment: check this and try https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/for-each-next-loop/

Comment: Do you code in VBA or VB.NET?

Comment: I code in VB.NET. Does this seem correct?



For Each CounterInteger as Integer in TeamString
  MessageBox.Show ----
Next CounterInteger

Comment: Did it do what it was supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good start in your comment but what is in your array is strings not integers so you would loop through the strings.

```
Dim TeamString(31) As String

        For Each Team As String In TeamString

            MessageBox.Show("Team Name:" & Team)

        Next
```